# PL/SQL - XML Validation errors

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd, xml-validation

I am validating an XML document against a schema. So far, all is going well, but there are some significant differences between the generated document and the schema (hence the validation). I've noticed that Oracle will stop validating after the first error is encountered. I'd like to be able to compile a list of errors and take them to the developers of the schema, but so far it looks like I can only get the next error if I resolve the current one - some of them I can't resolve on my own, but need to discuss with the other developers first.

Is there a way to get Oracle to print all validation errors?

**UPDATE**

I was working in Oracle 10g, but I have been told that Oracle 11 *can* return a list of validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most XML validators stop after the first failure. I think Oracle's is the same way.

Comment: Hmm ok. Do you know of any stand-alone tools (free, if possible) that will continue validating even after the first error?

Comment: stand-alone... no. But I'm pretty sure the schema validation in Eclipse will mark multiple errors. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that.